# How can I escape a DOM name in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a form element that I want to address via javascript, but it doesn't like the syntax.

```
<form name="mycache">
  <input type="hidden" name="cache[m][2]">
  <!-- ... -->
</form>
```

I want to be able to say:

```
document.mycache.cache[m][2]
```

but obviously I need to indicate that `cache[m][2]` is the whole name, and not an array reference to `cache`.  Can it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE: Actually, I was wrong, you can use [ or ] characters as part of a form elements id and/or name attribute.

Here's some code that proves it:

```
<html>
<body>

<form id="form1">

<input type='test' id='field[m][2]' name='field[m][2]' value='Chris'/>

<input type='button' value='Test' onclick='showtest();'/>

<script type="text/javascript">
function showtest() {
    var value = document.getElementById("field[m][2]").value;
    alert(value);
}
</script>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Update: You can also use the following to get the value from the form element:

```
var value = document.forms.form1["field[m][2]"].value;
```

Comment: That got me going the right direction....  being able to quote the name as a array index is nice.

Comment: The name can include [ and ] characters, but the id may not (even if browsers perform error recovery).

Answer (score 2):

Use `document.getElementsByName("input_name")` instead. Cross platform too. Win.

Comment: Actually getElementByName is not cross-platform. It's an IE specific thing.

Comment: Actually it is,
http://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByName

its just buggy from one browser to the next.

Comment: Actually, :), name attribute is only valid for form elements in XHTML, that's why it's buggy! It works fine if you're only using it for input select and textareas

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to add an id reference to the form element and use document.getElementById?

Answer (score 1):

-- and in the old days (in HTML3.2/4.01 transitional/XHTML1.0 transitional DOM-binding) you could use:

```
form.elements["cache[m][2]"]
```

-- but the elements-stuff is, as Chris Pietschmann showed, not necessary as these binding-schemes also allow direct access (though I personally would prefer the extra readability !-)

Comment: Well son of a gun.   I thought I tried that but could only get numeric entries to work.  But sure enough, it works.

Comment: .elements and a lot other element-collections (.images, .frames and so on !-) are exactly collections, so elements is accessible in both ways ...